# Scrolling only with the scrollbar and not the mousewheel

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

I have a page where a div has `overflow-y:scroll;`

I want that div to only support scrolling by using the `scrollbar-thumb` on the `scrollbar-track`, and not by scrolling with the mousewheel. The page should scroll past the element instead.

The page is rendered in a electron window and will never be used outside it so any fancy webkit solutions are very welcome.

I have tried to fiddle around in JavaScript (jQuery) returning `false` on `.on('mousewheel')` event but that prevents scrolling on the page surrounding the div when hovering the div and scrolling with the mousewheel.

How do i do this? Is it possible using only CSS, or do i need to use JavaScript? (which is fine).

here is the very simple markup

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
.nomousewheel {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 width: 300px;
 height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
 <meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="nomousewheel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam accusantium molestiae consectetur, libero rem illum, quia ipsum earum, commodi cum blanditiis hic quae esse reiciendis ut iure dignissimos ex magni? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam accusantium molestiae consectetur, libero rem illum, quia ipsum earum, commodi cum blanditiis hic quae esse reiciendis ut iure dignissimos ex magni? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veniam accusantium molestiae consectetur, libero rem illum, quia ipsum earum, commodi cum blanditiis hic quae esse reiciendis ut iure dignissimos ex magni?
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below website on how to handle the mousewheel event. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Basically you have to listen for the mouse wheel event and do a event.preventDeafult() to stop the default operation.